# Android SoundClound Java Wrapper API

Tags: android, soundcloud

I am trying to build an android app for android which using java wrapper API.
My idea is that my android app can receive the verification code via a callback URL after user visits authorizationUrl and allows access to the app.
For now, I am successfully redirect the user to my callback URL as blahblah.heroku.com and "PRINT" the verification code using oauth_verifier params. Something like this:

```
http://stormy-stream-176.heroku.com/?oauth_verifier=567890
```

Next I supposed to proceed as:

```
api.obtainAccessToken(VERIFICATION_CODE);
```

But I haven't thought of any way to pass the verification code on the android browser into the obtainAccessToken method.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution myself by consulting Java wrapper for SoundCloud API owner.
Instead of using browser for user authentication process, it's a lot easier to use username/password authentication like so:

```
SoundCloudAPI api = new SoundCloudAPI(consumerKey, consumerSecret, SoundCloudAPI.USE_PRODUCTION.with(OAuthVersion.V2_0));   
api.obtainAccessToken("username", "`password");
```

This will do the trick :)